# eslint rule for block braces on new line

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

I am trying to set the opening curly brace to start on a new line, but it is not working for me. I have tried to configure prettier, `eslint`, and `.editorconfig` but none seems to work for me.

- I am using VS Code
- Programming language: JavaScript

With Eslint

```
 rules: {
        "no-empty": "error",
        "no-multiple-empty-lines": "warn",
        "no-var": "error",
        "prefer-const": "error",
        "brace-style": [2, "allman", { allowSingleLine: false }],
    },
};
```

My code would be like this:

```
function foo() 
{

   if() 
      {

         return 0;

      }

}
```

Anyone with a solution that can work for me?

Comment: What is your IDE? May be your IDE forced its own rules?

Answer (score 0):

The rule has been move into a repository call [stylistic](https://eslint.style/).

This is my configuration, I had a problem like yours, and it appears I have to disable any `brace-style` rule before apply stylistic `brace-style` rule (the one used by a plugin for typescript). So, maybe, you have to also add `"brace-style": "off"` before  `"brace-style": [2, "allman", { allowSingleLine: false }],`

```json
{
    "root": true,
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
    ],
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": { "project": ["./tsconfig.json"] },
    "plugins": [
        "@typescript-eslint",
        "@stylistic"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "@stylistic/indent": ["error", 2],
        "@typescript-eslint/brace-style": "off",
        "@stylistic/brace-style": ["error", "allman"],
        "@typescript-eslint/strict-boolean-expressions": [
            2,
            {
                "allowString" : false,
                "allowNumber" : false
            }
        ]
    },
    "ignorePatterns": ["src/**/*.spec.ts", "dist"]
}
```

Guess it will help, even the topic is old.